# How do I split multiple delimited strings in a column in to a row and delete the duplicates in that row of IDs?

Tags: r, string, duplicates

Here's how my data frame looks like...

I

| Fasta headers |
| --- |
| ab12_P002;ab12_P003;ab12_P005;ab23_P002;ab23_P001 |
| ab45_P001;ab36_P001 |
| ab55_P001;ab55_P002 |

I managed to make a delimited string in a column into a row using code below

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
without_02473 %>% 
  mutate(`Fasta headers` = strsplit(as.character(`Fasta headers`), 
      ";")) %>%   unnest(`Fasta headers`)
```

which resulted in following

| Fasta headers |
| --- |
| ab12_P002 |
| ab12_P003 |
| ab12_P005 |
| ab23_P002 |
| ab23_P001 |
| ab45_P001 |

However, I would like to have following result in the end.

| Fasta headers |
| --- |
| ab12 |
| ab23 |
| ab45 |
| ab36 |

I tried to use group and filter, unnest(string_string_array), but I didn't manage to do it.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

We may use `separate_rows` to split the `Fasta headers` at the `;` to create new rows and then remove the suffix part starting from the `_` with `trimws`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- without_02473 %>% 
   separate_rows(`Fasta headers`, sep = ";") %>%
   mutate(`Fasta headers` = trimws(`Fasta headers`, whitespace = "_.*")) %>%
   distinct
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 5 × 1
  `Fasta headers`
  <chr>          
1 ab12           
2 ab23           
3 ab45           
4 ab36           
5 ab55   
library(writexl) 
write_xlsx(out, "first.xlsx")
```

---

Or may extract only the word before the `_` with `str_extract_all`, `unnest` the `list` column and get the `distinct` rows

```
library(stringr)
without_02473 %>%
   mutate(`Fasta headers` = str_extract_all(`Fasta headers`, 
        "\\w+(?=_)")) %>%
   unnest(`Fasta headers`) %>%
   distinct
```

#### data

```
without_02473 <- structure(list(`Fasta headers` = c("ab12_P002;ab12_P003;ab12_P005;ab23_P002;ab23_P001", 
"ab45_P001;ab36_P001", "ab55_P001;ab55_P002")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is slightly different approach:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

without_02473 %>% 
  separate_rows(`Fasta headers`) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(`Fasta headers`, 'ab\\d+')) %>% 
  distinct()
```

```
  `Fasta headers`
  <chr>          
1 ab12           
2 ab23           
3 ab45           
4 ab36           
5 ab55
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `strsplit` and remove everything after _ and filter `distinct`s like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
without_02473 %>%
  mutate(`Fasta headers` = strsplit(`Fasta headers`, ";")) %>%
  unnest(`Fasta headers`) %>%
  mutate(`Fasta headers` = sub("_[^_]+$", "", `Fasta headers`)) %>%
  distinct()
#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>   `Fasta headers`
#>   <chr>          
#> 1 ab12           
#> 2 ab23           
#> 3 ab45           
#> 4 ab36           
#> 5 ab55
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>